# 3075 Syntax Error in date in query expression - VBA / Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, syntax-error

I've got a bit of an issue with a section of SQL code. Every time when I try to export to Excel from this database I get a 3075 syntax error relating to the date. From what I could see it's got to do with the fact that the interpreted end date is < than the start date, which gives less than one day to export.

Just to clarify, I did have a good look through most 3075 questions here but couldn't get a resolution on this.
I don't have any experience in SQL and would appreciate anyone's input on this.

Here's the code:

```
strSql = "SELECT Min([Breaches and Errors Log].[Date Incident Reported]) AS [MinOfDate Incident Reported], Min([Breaches and Errors Log].[Date Incident Identified]) AS [MinOfDate Incident Identified], Min([Breaches and Errors Log].[Date Incident Commenced]) AS [MinOfDate Incident Commenced], Min([Breaches and Errors Log].[Date Incident Rectified]) AS [MinOfDate Incident Rectified], " & _
             " Max([Breaches and Errors Log].[Date Incident Reported]) AS [MaxOfDate Incident Reported], Max([Breaches and Errors Log].[Date Incident Identified]) AS [MaxOfDate Incident Identified], Max([Breaches and Errors Log].[Date Incident Commenced]) AS [MaxOfDate Incident Commenced], Max([Breaches and Errors Log].[Date Incident Rectified]) AS [MaxOfDate Incident Rectified] FROM [Breaches and Errors Log]"
```

Here's the error that I'm getting:

[image]

Comment: Looks like you are missing a `Group By` part of your query.

Comment: Thanks but as mentioned before I don't have any experience with SQL. Could you please dumb it down? Based on what I could find online my groups are just concatenated, but then again, I'm new to this.

Comment: Use Access query builder to help construct the SQL. That will give you syntax to replicate the SQL in VBA.